# Explicitly make a string into raw string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading reading path to the registry from a text file. The registry path is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MYAPP\6.3
```

I store this registry in a variable :

```
REGISTRY_KEY
```

Then I strip the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE part from the string and try to read the value at the key.

```
if REGISTRY_KEY.split('\\')[0] == "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE":
        keyPath = REGISTRY_KEY.strip("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\")
        try:
            key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyPath)
            value = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "InstallPath")[0] 
        except IOError as err:
            print(err)
```

I get the  following error

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

However if I do it manually like

```
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'Software\MYAPP\6.3')
```

OR

```
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software\\MYAPP\\6.3")
```

it works.

So is there any way I can make the keyPath variable to either be a raw string or contain double '\'

PS:I am using Python 3.3

Comment: what is `keyPath` before you use it in OpenKey (try printing it)

Comment: "raw" string and escaped slashes are only used for literal typing strings. The string itself isn't stored with either.

Comment: Is it possible that the string you read from the file include a newlines character? Could you try to use `keyPath.strip()` in the call to `OpenKey`?

Comment: @SylvainDefresne it worked...been scratching my head over it since yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A raw str is a way of entering the string so you do not need to escape special characters.  Another  way to enter the same str is to escape the special characters (blackslash being one of them).  They would have the same data.  So really your question doesn't have an answer.
- You are also using `strip` incorrectly, but it would not matter for this particular string. Because the first character after the first `\` is `S` and `S` is not in your strip command and your key ends in a digit also not in your strip command.  But you will want to fix it so other keys are not messed up by this.  You got lucky on this string.

> ```
> >>> r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MYAPP\6.3".strip("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\")
> 'Software\\MYAPP\\6.3'
> ```

- As for your real problem.  There is something else about the string that is wrong.  Try `print repr(keyPath)` before your call to `OpenKey`

EDIT: looks like SylvainDefresne guessed correctly about a newline character on the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Your `REGISTRY_KEY.strip()` call is not doing what you think it's doing. It doesn't remove the string `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\` from the beginning of the string. Instead, it removes the characters `H`, `K`, `E`, etc., in any order, from both ends of the string. This is why it works when you manually put in what you expect.

As for your original question, a double backslash is an escape sequence that produces a single backslash in your string, so it is not necessary to convert `keyPath` to double slashes.

Comment: he is using it incorrectly, but is not the problem in this case

Comment: Well, that's why `keyPath` is not found, it's because he's producing it incorrectly.

Comment: good question, not enough info to answer.  maybe its read in wrong.  anyway try the strip command as he is using it.